# Error while deploying my project from jDeveloper to Weblogic Server 10.3

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper, business-process-management, sqlexception

I am trying to deploy my project from Oracle jDeveloper to remote Weblogic Server.

I am getting an SQL Exception. See below log:

```
[11:09:55 PM] ---- Deployment started. ----
[11:09:55 PM] Target platform is (Weblogic 10.3).
[11:09:55 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[11:09:55 PM] Building...
[11:10:04 PM] Deploying profile...
[11:10:04 PM] Updating revision id for the SOA Project 'bpm_poc_project.jpr' to '1.0'..
[11:10:04 PM] Wrote Archive Module to /xyz/home/abc/jdeveloper/mywork/bpm_poc_app/bpm_poc_project/deploy/sca_bpm_poc_project_rev1.0.jar
[11:10:04 PM] Deploying sca_bpm_poc_project_rev1.0.jar to partition "default" on server AdminServer [http://localhost:7001]
[11:10:04 PM] Processing sar=/xyz/home/akrishn2/jdeveloper/mywork/bpm_poc_app/bpm_poc_project/deploy/sca_bpm_poc_project_rev1.0.jar
[11:10:04 PM] Adding sar file - /xyz/home/akrishn2/jdeveloper/mywork/bpm_poc_app/bpm_poc_project/deploy/sca_bpm_poc_project_rev1.0.jar
[11:10:04 PM] Preparing to send HTTP request for deployment
[11:10:04 PM] Creating HTTP connection to host:localhost, port:7001
[11:10:04 PM] Sending internal deployment descriptor
[11:10:04 PM] Sending archive - sca_bpm_poc_project_rev1.0.jar
[11:11:26 PM] Received HTTP response from the server, response code=500
[11:11:26 PM] Error deploying archive sca_bpm_poc_project_rev1.0.jar to partition "default" on server AdminServer [http://localhost:7001]
[11:11:26 PM] HTTP error code returned [500]
[11:11:26 PM] Error message from server: There was an error deploying the composite on AdminServer: javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntax

ErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBTYPE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904 Call: SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?)) bind => [default, bpm_poc_project, 1.0, soa_347b99f8-fa8d-4671-a2f8-2b5446723ab2, BPMN] Query: ReadAllQuery(name="CubeProcess.findCubeProcessesInComposite" referenceClass=CubeProcess sql="SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?))"); nested exception is: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBTYPE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904 Call: SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?)) bind => [default, bpm_poc_project, 1.0, soa_347b99f8-fa8d-4671-a2f8-2b5446723ab2, BPMN] Query: ReadAllQuery(name="CubeProcess.findCubeProcessesInComposite" referenceClass=CubeProcess sql="SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?))"): EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBTYPE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904 Call: SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?)) bind => [default, bpm_poc_project, 1.0, soa_347b99f8-fa8d-4671-a2f8-2b5446723ab2, BPMN] Query: ReadAllQuery(name="CubeProcess.findCubeProcessesInComposite" referenceClass=CubeProcess sql="SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?))"); nested exception is: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBTYPE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904 Call: SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?)) bind => [default, bpm_poc_project, 1.0, soa_347b99f8-fa8d-4671-a2f8-2b5446723ab2, BPMN] Query: ReadAllQuery(name="CubeProcess.findCubeProcessesInComposite" referenceClass=CubeProcess sql="SELECT PROCESSID, ORGANIZATIONALUNITID, HASGLOBALCREATIONTASKS, TARGETNAMESPACE, COMPOSITENAME, STATUS, SCALABEL, PROCESSNAME, LABEL, DOMAINNAME, COMPOSITEDN, PROCESSTYPE, CREATIONDATE, SUBTYPE, REVISION, UNDEPLOYDATE FROM BPM_CUBE_PROCESS WHERE (((((DOMAINNAME = ?) AND (COMPOSITENAME = ?)) AND (REVISION = ?)) AND (SCALABEL = ?)) AND (PROCESSTYPE = ?))").
```

Can someone give some pointers ?

#### Update:

I managed to get rid of the above error (not completely though... read through) by making my project as BPEL project (while creating the project. It was BPMN earlier. Overlooked this option earlier).

The problem now is I get the same error occasionaly with the same setup. I get the error even without doing any changes to the project and deploying the same to weblogic.

Can someone provide some hints ? Is it that there might be some schema version mismatch while trying to deploy from 11.x jDeveloper to 10.x weblogic server ?

Here is my schema version detail:

```
SQL> select comp_name, version from schema_version_registry;

COMP_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION
------------------------------
Oracle B2B
11.1.1.2.0

BAM Services
11.1.1.4.0

Metadata Services
11.1.1.2.0


COMP_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION
------------------------------
Oracle Internet Directory
11.1.1.3.0

SDP Messaging
11.1.1.2.0

Oracle Repository Upgrade Utility
11.1.1.4.0


COMP_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION
------------------------------
SOA Infrastructure Services
11.1.1.3.0


7 rows selected.
```

Below is the version info related to jDeveloper:
About

> Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1 11.1.1.4.0 Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.4.0 Build JDEVADF_11.1.1.4.0_GENERIC_101227.1736.5923 Copyright Â© 1997, 2011 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. IDE Version: 11.1.1.4.37.59.23 Product ID: oracle.jdeveloper Product Version: 11.1.1.4.37.59.23
>   Version
>
> Component Version ========= ======= ADF Business Components 11.1.1.59.23 BPMN Editor 11.1.1.4.0.5682 Java(TM) Platform 1.6.0_13 Oracle IDE 11.1.1.4.37.59.23 SOA Composite Editor 11.1.1.4.0.56.82 Versioning Support 11.1.1.4.37.59.23

Answer (score 1):

The `BPM_CUBE_PROCESS` table on the database you're deploying against doesn't seem to have a `SUBTYPE` column. I'd start by checking the spelling, checking the table definition, running the query manually, and looking in to the possibility of a table in the schema you're connecting to masking the one you're expecting to see.

Comment: Is there a possibility that I'm using an incorrect schema ? Since, I see missing columns in my DB for the table BPM_CUBE_PROCESS I suspect an incorrect schema to be the issue ?

Can someone suggest ?

Comment: Depends if your JDBC connection is using the same credentials as when you look at the table yourself. If it's different then it may have its own version of the table (or a view, or a synonym to someone else's different version...).